# mousemove and touchmove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I really like [this visual effect](http://lab.simurai.com/monster/). I want to make this available in iphone or ipad with touchmove. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the JS:

```
$(document).bind('mousemove',function(e){
    var docW = $(window).width();
    var docH = $(window).height();

    var diffX = (docW/2) - e.clientX;
    var diffY = (docH/2)-100 - e.clientY;

    var dist = distance(docW/2,docH/2, e.clientX, e.clientY);
    var distM = distance(docW/2,(docH/2)+60, e.clientX, e.clientY);

        // eye                          
        var eye_background = Math.floor( diffX /-30 ) +'px '+ Math.floor( diffY /-30 ) +'px';       
        var eye_translate = Math.floor(diffX/-50 )+'px, '+ Math.floor(diffY/-100 )+'px';    
        $(".eye").css({"background-position":eye_background, "-webkit-transform":'translate3d('+eye_translate+',0)',"-moz-transform":'translate('+eye_translate+')',"-o-transform":'translate('+eye_translate+')',"-ms-transform":'translate('+eye_translate+')' });



});
```

Basically, my question is how can I make this work on apple?

Answer (score 0):

You should start a listener on mousedown and stop it on mouseup.
Meanwhile a listener will loop *(for example requestanimationfame or setInterval() )* your `//eye` method.

This is a common process in webGL for example.
[example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama_fisheye.html#L144)

http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Comment: thank you for your quick answer..really appreciated it... but i still learn javascript... is there any simple way to do this for apple...